# How do I create an installer for a class library in VS 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, class-library

I am hoping to get some help to figure out how to create an installer in visual studio 2013. 
My class library project generates a DLL called DataTest. The solution also has an xml file called config.xml. Currently when I build the solution the DataTest DLL ends up in the bin folder (and the config.xml is just a static file somewhere). What I want the installer to do is copy/install the  DataTest DLL to C:\MyData\Test and the xml file should end up in C:\MyData\Config.

I have found this http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2014/04/24/visual-studio-2013-installer-projects-ndash-hello-world-installer.aspx which seems like a good place to start but I don't have much experience with the different configurations in VS so I don't really know how to do what I want to do.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want an installer? NuGet is now the standard way to distribute a library.

Comment: The class library is not for visual studio....it will be used by another program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want an MSI file to do the install because you posted that link, so you're using the Visual Studio Installer projects extension.

This might also help, old but still applies:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/getting-started-with-setup-projects/

Configurations in Visual Studio don't really have much to do with this. The Bin, Release, Debug folders in your build are nothing to do with where you want to deploy the file on the target system. For example, if you have a Dll that you want to install in the Common Files Folder then you select that folder in the File System view of the setup project and just drag and drop the file in there. The same principle applies to the Program Files folder, which is the usual place for applications.